# Kotlin enforce value of property being set by a specific class

Tags: kotlin

Is it possible to enforce the value of a property to be obtained only by another class?

I have `val itemValue by ItemValueDelegator()` and `ItemValueDelegator` returns an enum (ItemValue) after some business rule logic.

can I enforce somehow that the value of `itemValue` is always obtained from `ItemValueDelegator`?

I want to make impossible to do: `val itemValue = ItemValue.STOCK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val` modifier already makes it impossible to assign new value to it. Calls on `itemValue` will only call `getValue()` function in the `ItemValueDelegator`. What you can do is hide the enums within the class of the delegate and make the `itemValue` hold the ordinal.

Edit:

You need to perform runtime validation. In the `init` block should check if the `itemVal` is provided by a delegate. That involves using kotlin-reflect and checking that underlying `KProperty` delegate is of type `ItemValueDelegator` or `null`, if isn't, just `throw error("itemValue should be provided by ItemValueDelegator")`

Comment: Thanks. Something that I missed explaining. Item `val itemValue` is in fact `override val itemValue` that can be used by many classes. In the team, it's easy for a developer (that is new to the project or is unaware of the logic) to do `val itemValue = ItemValue.STOCK` instead of `val itemValue by ItemValueDelegator()`. The delegator has specific logic to determine the itemValue. I was thinking if some pattern/definition existed that enforced that if we want to assign a value to `override val itemValue`, one must use the delegator.

Comment: You need to perform runtime validation. In the `init` block should check if the itemVal is provided by a delegate. That involves using kotlin-reflect and checking that underlying `KProperty` delegate is of type `ItemValueDelegator` or null, if isn't, just `throw error("itemValue should be provided by ItemValueDelegator")`

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the suggestion.